# PowerShell Script to Find All Machines a User is Logged On To?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to be able to audit our domain and find all machines that a particular user is logged into.  Does anyone have a way to do this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a script I use to generate an Excel sheet for every PC on a domain and who is currently logged on. Save it to a .ps1 file and run it after putting in the OU path to search. I copied most of this from somewhere off the net a long time ago.

```
# This way it won't die when a machine is unavailable
# It's powered off, or the machine account was left behind, etc
$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"

function GetList 
{ param ([string]$base)
    # Give this function the LDAP search string and it will search there
    $blah = [ADSI]"$base"
    $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=computer)"
    $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $blah

    $PropList = "cn","operatingSystem"
    foreach ($i in $PropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}
    $Results = $objSearcher.FindAll()

    foreach ($objResult in $Results)
    {
        $OS = $objResult.Properties.operatingsystem
        If ($OS -match "Windows")
        {
            Echo $objResult.Properties.cn | Out-File -Append -FilePath $OutFile
        }
    }
}

# This is for output
$Outbook = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Outbook.visible = $True

$Workbook = $Outbook.Workbooks.Add()
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Machine Name"
$Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Remote User"

$Formatting = $Worksheet.UsedRange
$Formatting.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$Formatting.Font.ColorIndex = 11
$Formatting.Font.Bold = $True

$intRow = 2

# Put the path to the OU with your computer accounts here, if you need more than one, put another GetList line
GetList "LDAP://OU=Computers,dc=yourdomain,dc=name"

foreach ($strComputer in Get-Content $OutFile)
{
    $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1)  = $strComputer.ToUpper()

    # Using .NET to ping the servers
    $Ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    $Reply = $Ping.send($strComputer)


    if($Reply.status -eq "success")
    {
        $RemoteSys = Get-WmiObject -Comp $strComputer -CL Win32_ComputerSystem
        If ($?)
        {
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $RemoteUser = $RemoteSys.UserName
        }
        Else
        {
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "Error"
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        $Worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "Not Pingable"
    }

    $Formatting.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

    $Reply = ""
    $pwage = ""
    $intRow = $intRow + 1
}

$Formatting.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
cls
```

Answer (score 3):

(Courtesy of [PeetersOnline](http://www.peetersonline.nl/index.php/powershell/oneliner-get-logged-on-users-with-powershell/) via a search for "Powershell logged in users")

```
function Get-MyLoggedOnUsers
{
 param([string]$Computer)
 Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $Computer | Select Antecedent -Unique | %{“{0}{1}” -f $_.Antecedent.ToString().Split(‘”‘)[1], $_.Antecedent.ToString().Split(‘”‘)[3]}
}
```

I don't have the code handy anymore, but I had done something similar in VBScript by looking at the Terminal Services Sessions.  Being VBScript and not having access to the .NET frameworks, I had to do a hack to get there.  (I think I looked at session IDs of explorer.exe...)

Powershell has access to the .NET frameworks, so you could look in MSDN for Terminal Services for assistance.

Comment: Hi, why the script returns: Laptop425SYSTEM                                                                                          
Laptop425LOCAL SERVICE                                                                                    
Laptop425NETWORK SERVICE                                                                                  
MYDOMAINusername                                                                                          
Laptop425ANONYMOUS LOGON  ----- how to get MYDOMAIN\username only ?